# Spring MVC form parameters and query parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring 4 MVC, I'm trying to figure out how to accept both form parameters and query parameters posted to my rest endpoint and also trigger validation, but am struggling to figure out how to get this to work.

Ideally, my controller would look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someurl", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public someMethod(@Valid @ModelAttribute Order order, @RequestParam String parm1, @RequestParam String parm2) {

}
```

I need to post the form parameters to the controller URL along with some query parameters and a Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the `Order` class has the `order_id` and `order_x` attributes, with the following endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someurl", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public someMethod(@Valid @ModelAttribute Order order, BindingResult validation,  @RequestParam String parm1, @RequestParam String parm2) {

}
```

If a client sends a POST request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type with following **request body**:

```
order_id=1&order_x=something&parm1=foo&parm2=bar
```

then an `Order` instance with `{order_id=1, order_x=something}` will be instantiated. In addition, `parm1` and `parm2` will contain `foo` and `bar`, respectively. `BindingResult` contains validation results for a preceding command or form object (the immediately preceding method argument).
[See this discussion about Query Parameters in POST requests.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) Also [Forms Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13) is a good reference.

Comment: This doesn't really work. If I take off the @Valid annotation, it makes it into the method, but it doesn't map things correctly. The request parameters are mapped OK, but I lose the form values.